# MEAN.io setup with WebStorm

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

MEAN.io http://mean.io/#!/ is getting popular for FullStack MEAN framework (Mongo db, Express, Angular JS, Node), Im able to follow instruction and setup MEAN.io so far successfully, now I want to integrate MEAN.io with WebStorm so I can proceed further development in WebStorm.

How can I run MEAN.io project in Webstorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Install MEAN.io and setup your project following given instructions:**
https://github.com/linnovate/mean

[Watch Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUtWtSF_VNY)

**Running MEAN.io project in WebStorm:**

1- Open your project in Webstorm

2- **Run->Edit Configurations** to provide Node path, Working directory and JavaScript file "server.js" as following:

[image]

3- Save Configurations and Run project